How does Visual Studio know about Microsoft Logging placeholders?
In a .NET C# application with Microsoft logging, one will have logging statements like the following, with a message that may include brace-delimited placeholders followed by an ordered sequence of values to fill the placeholders with:
  logger.LogInformation("{numRequests} orders for {item} were received in the past hour", 47, "doughnuts");

If the number of parameters after the message parameter differs from the number of placeholders, Visual Studio, flags the discrepancy. How does Visual Studio know?

Is Visual Studio hard-coded to recognize Microsoft Logging statements and apply special treatment to them? In other words, not something I could replicate when defining a method of my own where I'd like this to occur.
Or is there a generally available way of declaring a string parameter as a template and associating it with a parameter array? Could I use this in a method declaration of my own?

Yes, I know about formattable strings, but I'm curious about what's behind the way it works in the logging methods, without formattable strings.

What's the error code of the error if there's a mis-match? I'm going to guess that it's a Rosyln Analyzer which is included in the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package

Most likely this Roslyn Analyzer https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers?tab=readme-ov-file#microsoftcodeanalysisnetanalyzers

@canton7 Now that I look at it, after a green squiggle appears under the statement, the popup is very specific: "Number of parameters supplied in the logging message template do not match the number of named placeholders". Ignoring the use of "do" where it should read "does", I guess this is  specific to this library, not a language feature. Thanks to you and Alex for the pointer to Roslyn Analyzer.

The error code would tell us for sure!

@canton7 CA2017, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2017


You can refer to this rule provided by .NET Analyzer:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/NetAnalyzers/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.sarif#L3614

Here is an example of checking whether the placeholders match the parameters in logging statements.   You can see information that whether it matches validly in the console.


LoggingAnalyzer.cs
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class LoggingAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(
        "LOG001",
        "Logging placeholder mismatch",
        "The number of placeholders in the message does not match the number of arguments",
        "Logging",
        DiagnosticSeverity.Error,
        isEnabledByDefault: true);
 
    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);
 
    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
        context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeInvocation, SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
    }
 
    private void AnalyzeInvocation(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var invocation = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;
        var memberAccess = invocation.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
 
        if (memberAccess == null || !memberAccess.Name.ToString().StartsWith("Log"))
            return;
 
        var arguments = invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments;
        if (arguments.Count < 2)
            return;
 
        var messageArgument = arguments[0];
        var messageExpression = messageArgument.Expression as LiteralExpressionSyntax;
 
        if (messageExpression == null || messageExpression.Kind() != SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression)
            return;
 
        var message = messageExpression.Token.ValueText;
        int placeholderCount = Regex.Matches(message, @"\{[^}]+\}").Count;
        int argumentCount = arguments.Count - 1;
 
        if (placeholderCount != argumentCount)
        {
            var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocation.GetLocation());
            context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
        }
    }
}

Program.cs
using System;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
 
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string code = @"
            using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
 
            public class TestClass
            {
                private ILogger<TestClass> _logger;
 
                public TestClass(ILogger<TestClass> logger)
                {
                    _logger = logger;
                }
 
                public void TestMethod()
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("" orders for {item} were received in the past hour"", 47, ""doughnuts"");
                }
            }";
 
        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("TestAssembly", new[] { tree });
 
        var analyzer = new LoggingAnalyzer();
        var analyzers = ImmutableArray.Create<DiagnosticAnalyzer>(analyzer);
 
        var compilationWithAnalyzers = compilation.WithAnalyzers(analyzers);
        var diagnostics = compilationWithAnalyzers.GetAnalyzerDiagnosticsAsync().Result;
 
        foreach (var diagnostic in diagnostics)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(diagnostic);
        }
    }
}


Neat (and complicated, but it's interesting to see how this works under the hood/boot, using an attribute and the DiagnosticAnalyzer subclass). Thanks.
